# question on struct in c++

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
struct product{
    int weight;
    float price;
};
int main(){
    string  mystr;
    product  prod;
    product *pointer;
    pointer=&prod;
    getline(cin,pointer->price);
    return 0;
}
```

but it shows me the mistake

> no instance  of overloaded  function "getline" matches argument list

What is the mistake?

Comment: @Neil Why the rollback? @davit After 132 asked questions you should have figured out how to format your posts. Please spend a little more effort.

Comment: Trying to work out how this is a question on struct

Comment: @pmr I am having some  network problems (if you live in the UK, do NOT use three.co.uk as your ISP) , and some finger trouble. Rolled back to a more sensible version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is that getline returns string, not float.

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
pointer->price = atof(str.c_str());
```

Comment: Technically, `getline` returns an `istream&`. It takes a string reference as an output parameter.

Answer (score 13):

The mistake is that you are trying to read a line of text into a `float`. Reading in an entire line requires that you read into a string. If you just want to read in a float from input, simply write:

```
cin >> pointer->price;
```

Which will read input up to the next whitespace and attempt to interpret it as a `float`.

Answer (score 4):

The second argument to [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) is supposed to be a reference to a string, not a float as you've used.

Or the [other overload of `getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) you can use takes in a `char*` and a `streamsize`.  Either way, the arguments you've specified do not match any overload of `getline`, and that is why you received the error you described.